# Can't create Lotus Notes objects

Tags: vb.net, lotus-notes

I have IBM Notes 9 and Visual Studio 2010. I'm trying to create a NOTESSESSION instance both of the following ways

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-msnet/index.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18517/Lotus-Notes-Integration-with-Microsoft-NET-Platfor

but get the error *'New' cannot be used on an interface.* After trying every permutation I can think of, still no luck. What do I need to do differently to create lotus objects?

```
Dim notesSession As New lotus.NOTESSESSION
```

Reference *Lotus Notes Automation Classes* **Interop.lotus.dll**

Comment: Since this is interop the first thing that comes to mind was how Microsoft did their interop with Office. They'd have interface with one name and a class with the exact same name appended with the word `Class`. I've never worked with Domino before but is there a `NotesSessionClass` by any chance?

Comment: I did look for this as well. As far as I can tell there are only interfaces in the imported lotus namespace. The namespace doesn't even show up contextually after typing new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the IBM.com article that you referenced, in Figure 1, notice that it lists "Lotus Notes Automation Classes" and "Lotus Domino Objects". It looks like you selected "Lotus Notes Automation Classes", but those are OLE classes and the reference was apparently generated as an interface. You want the second, the "Lotus Domino Objects", which are COM classes. Those can be instantiated in the way reflected in the documentation.

If you don't see "Lotus Domino Objects" in the references dialog, you may have a registration issue, which can be solved with the command **regsvr32 nlsxbe.dll** (issued from the Notes program folder).

You may need to be aware, however, of the fact that the Notes COM classes are not supported on Win64 (see the bottom of this [IBM technote](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21454291) for confirmatiion of that.) If you didn't find them registered, that could be why. They do mostly work, but there are a few known issues - e.g., with NotesDatabase methods that return collections of design elements. If you need to be sure that you are only working with vendor-supported APIs, though, you're going to have to look at the other available approaches to working the Notes data.

Comment: I was unable to add the reference you mentioned due to working on an Excel Add-In targeting an old .NET framework. However moving to a more recent framework allowed this to work correctly for me. Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for asking this question, I have roughly the same problem in Windows10/Excel2016/VisualBasic7.1. I do have Lotus Domino Objects imported, but received an error `ActiveX component can't create object` when performing `Set Session = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")`.How did you update the library? Thank you

Comment: Is your project 32 bit or 64?

Answer (score 1):

We have a reference to Interop.Domino.dll and use the follow class to instantiate:

```
Public NotInheritable Class LotusNotesSession
    Implements IEMailSession

    Private m_session As NotesSession

    Public Sub New(ByVal password As String)
        m_session = New NotesSession
        m_session.Initialize(password)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I have Notes 9 installed on my machine (Windows 8). Do you know where Interop.Domino.dll would be found?

Comment: It comes with the Notes Client install as far as I know.

Comment: It came with my Notes 8.5 install but not with a Notes 9 install on another machine. Was able to find it, thanks.

Comment: Hi! @AndrewMortimer please can you be more specific. does it mean that Interop.Domino.dll file is necessary but is not provided with Lotus Notes 9? If yes do I need to just copy it from an older version in order to paste it in my computer? Thank you