# ActiveX component can't create object when creating Lotus.NotesSession in VBA 64-bits

Tags: vba, activex, lotus-notes, 32bit-64bit, lotus-domino

```
Sub Macro()
    Dim Session As NotesSession
    Set Session = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")
End Sub
```

In Excel 32-bits it throws no error.

But in Excel 64-bits, it throws this error :

> Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object

I think the reason is that `Lotus Domino Objects` library is `32-bit` (as `Lotus` itself is a 32-bits app), thus the object `NotesSession` cannot be created on an `Excel 64-bits`.

I tried registering the ActiveX component by running `regsvr32` on `c:\notes\nlsxbe.dll` then `C:\Notes\notesw32.reg` in a command prompt. It registered the DLL successfully but still didn’t solve the issue.

Comment: Some components can be fixed by loading into a surrogate process, http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/04/com-windows-wow3264-add-extra-isolation.html .  I'm not sure Lotus Notes will co-operate..

Comment: Thank you for your help but I didn't understand how to perform it

Comment: Did you search and find this previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655598/lotus-domino-on-64-bit-system-could-not-create-automation-object-error-208

Comment: @RichardSchwartz: very good.

Comment: Also, you should be aware that even though it is possible to make the Notes/Domino COM classes (mostly) work on a 64 bit system, IBM does not officially support them.  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21454291

Comment: Actually, my link to a previous question was not right. That was referring to calling COM classes from a user-created DLL, not to calling the Lotus classes. My mistake. I'm sure there's been a previous question here in StackOverflow regarding getting nlsxbe.dll registered on a 64 bit server.  This gives the command, but it's the same one that Takichiii says he already tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322360/cant-create-lotus-notes-objects/31323051#31323051